# Transpose character separated list to hierarchy using xsl

Tags: list, xslt, hierarchy, xslt-2.0

Each product in my feed has category node like this:

```
<categories>
  <category>För henne &gt; Ansikte</category>
  <category>För henne &gt; Pumps &amp; klackskor</category>
  <category>För henne &gt; Stövlar &amp; stövletter</category>
  <category>För honom &gt; Badkläder</category>
  ...
</categories>
```

Where `&gt;` separates parent from child category.

What I want to do is have category tree like this:

```
<categories>
  <category name="För henne">
    <categories>
      <category name="Ansikte"/>
      <category name="Pumps &amp; klackskor"/>
      <category name="Stövlar &amp; stövletter"/>
    </categories>
  </category>
  <category name="För honom">
    <categories>
      <category name="Badkläder"/>
    </categories>
  </category>
</categories>
```

How can I achieve this with xsl?

Comment: Jonica, please see my solution including the addendum. Please advise if I have understood the rules of transformation correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I. XSLT 1.0 solution**:

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kCategory" match="category"
  use="substring-before(., ' >')"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "category
    [generate-id()
    =
     generate-id(key('kCategory', substring-before(., ' >'))[1])
    ]">
  <category name="{substring-before(., ' >')}">
    <categories>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="inGroup"
        select="key('kCategory', substring-before(., ' >'))"/>
    </categories>
  </category>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="category" mode="inGroup">
   <category name="{substring-after(., '> ')}"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="category"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<categories>
  <category>För henne > Ansikte</category>
  <category>För henne > Pumps &amp; klackskor</category>
  <category>För henne > Stövlar &amp; stövletter</category>
  <category>För honom > Badkläder</category>
  ...
</categories>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<categories>
   <category name="För henne">
      <categories>
         <category name="Ansikte"/>
         <category name="Pumps &amp; klackskor"/>
         <category name="Stövlar &amp; stövletter"/>
      </categories>
   </category>
   <category name="För honom">
      <categories>
         <category name="Badkläder"/>
      </categories>
   </category>
  ...
</categories>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Proper use of the Muenchian grouping method.
2. Proper use and overriding of the identity rule.
3. Proper use of keys and modes.

---

**II. Generic XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="my xs">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:sequence select="my:grouping(*)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:function name="my:grouping">
  <xsl:param name="pStrings" as="xs:string*"/>

  <xsl:if test="$pStrings[1]">
      <categories>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="$pStrings"
            group-by="tokenize(., ' > ')[1]">

            <category name="{current-grouping-key()}">
             <xsl:variable name="vnewStrings" as="xs:string*">
                 <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                   <xsl:sequence select="substring-after(., ' > ')"/>
                 </xsl:for-each>
             </xsl:variable>
             <xsl:sequence select="my:grouping($vnewStrings)"/>
            </category>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </categories>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<categories>
  <category>A > AB1 > AB1C1</category>
  <category>A > AB2 > AB2C1 > AB2C1D1</category>
  <category>A > AB2 > AB2C1</category>
  <category>A > AB2 > AB2C1 > AB2C3</category>
  <category>F > XY1 > XY1Z1</category>
  <category>F > XY2 > XY2Z1 > XY2Z1T1</category>
  <category>F > XY2 > XY2Z1</category>
  <category>F > XY2 > XY2Z1 > XY2Z3</category>
</categories>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<categories>
   <category name="A">
      <categories>
         <category name="AB1">
            <categories>
               <category name="AB1C1"/>
            </categories>
         </category>
         <category name="AB2">
            <categories>
               <category name="AB2C1">
                  <categories>
                     <category name="AB2C1D1"/>
                     <category name="AB2C3"/>
                  </categories>
               </category>
            </categories>
         </category>
      </categories>
   </category>
   <category name="F">
      <categories>
         <category name="XY1">
            <categories>
               <category name="XY1Z1"/>
            </categories>
         </category>
         <category name="XY2">
            <categories>
               <category name="XY2Z1">
                  <categories>
                     <category name="XY2Z1T1"/>
                     <category name="XY2Z3"/>
                  </categories>
               </category>
            </categories>
         </category>
      </categories>
   </category>
</categories>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Use of `<xsl:for-each-group>`
2. Use of the standard XSLT functions: `current-group()` and `current-grouping-key()` .
3. Recursion with stop condition: empty parameter.

Comment: Tried and it works for the example input. How would we modify transformation to avoid duplicates and support n-level categories?

Comment: What do you mean by "to avoid duplicates" -- they *are* avoided.

Comment: For example if you have two times `<category>För honom > Badkläder</category>` in the input, category `Badkläder` will show up twice in the output.

Comment: @JovicaZaric, See my updated answer for a generic, XSLT 2.0 solution that correctly processes lists of categories of any length and eliminates duplication.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative XSLT 2.0 style-sheet, which I believe is the simplest yet generic solution.

**This transformation...**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:variable name="sep" select="' &gt; '" />

<xsl:template match="categories" name="cat-grouper">
  <xsl:param name="cat-strs" as="xs:string*" select="category" />
  <categories>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$cat-strs[contains(.,$sep)]" group-by="substring-before(.,$sep)">
      <category name="{current-grouping-key()}">
        <xsl:call-template name="cat-grouper">
          <xsl:with-param name="cat-strs" select="for $s in current-group() return substring-after($s,$sep)" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </category>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$cat-strs[not(contains(.,$sep))]" group-by=".">
      <category name="{current-grouping-key()}" />
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </categories> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...applied to the following input** (adapted from the OP's sample input to address his comment in relation to a double occurrence of `<category>För honom > Badkläder</category>` in the input)**...**

```
<categories>
  <category>För henne &gt; Ansikte</category>
  <category>För henne &gt; Pumps &amp; klackskor</category>
  <category>För henne &gt; Stövlar &amp; stövletter</category>
  <category>För honom &gt; Badkläder</category>
  <category>För honom &gt; Badkläder</category>
</categories>
```

**...yields...**

```
<categories>
   <category name="För henne">
      <categories>
         <category name="Ansikte"/>
         <category name="Pumps &amp; klackskor"/>
         <category name="Stövlar &amp; stövletter"/>
      </categories>
   </category>
   <category name="För honom">
      <categories>
         <category name="Badkläder"/>
      </categories>
   </category>
</categories>
```

### Notes

Some simplicity is gained by dual-purposing the one and only template. It is both a matching template for the `categories` root element, and a named template for processing lists of category strings.

### Another one

Here is another alternative solution. If prefer the first one I offered you, but it's worth having a look at this one. With the similar use of tokenize(), you might consider this one just a tweak on Dimitre's solution.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:variable name="sep" select="' &gt; '" />

<xsl:template match="categories" name="cat-grouper">
  <xsl:param name="cat-strs" as="xs:string*" select="category" />
  <categories>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$cat-strs" group-by="tokenize(.,$sep)[1]">
      <category name="{current-grouping-key()}">
        <xsl:variable name="subcats" select="
          for $s in current-group()[contains(.,$sep)]
            return substring-after($s,$sep)" />
        <xsl:if test="exists($subcats)">
          <xsl:call-template name="cat-grouper">
            <xsl:with-param name="cat-strs" select="$subcats" />
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>  
      </category>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </categories> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Addendum

Here is the resultant output from applying my first solution to Dimitre's input document. I am asking the OP to advise whether or not this a correct interpretation of his rules of transformation. This is my understanding, but perhaps I have got it wrong?

```
<categories>
   <category name="A">
      <categories>
         <category name="AB1">
            <categories>
               <category name="AB1C1"/>
            </categories>
         </category>
         <category name="AB2">
            <categories>
               <category name="AB2C1">
                  <categories>
                     <category name="AB2C1D1"/>
                     <category name="AB2C3"/>
                  </categories>
               </category>
               <category name="AB2C1"/>
            </categories>
         </category>
      </categories>
   </category>
   <category name="F">
      <categories>
         <category name="XY1">
            <categories>
               <category name="XY1Z1"/>
            </categories>
         </category>
         <category name="XY2">
            <categories>
               <category name="XY2Z1">
                  <categories>
                     <category name="XY2Z1T1"/>
                     <category name="XY2Z3"/>
                  </categories>
               </category>
               <category name="XY2Z1"/>
            </categories>
         </category>
      </categories>
   </category>
</categories>
```

Comment: Sean, You don't have to "believe" and the belief that this "is the simplest yet generic solution" is contrary to the facts. Just count the number of lines ( after cutting the long and unreadable ones in order to have a well-formatted code (as in the other answer :) ). Also, count the number of instructions, such as `xsl:for-each-group`, `xsl:call-template`, the number of named templates, the number of XPath 2.0 complex expressions (containing a `for` clause). Compare these numbers for the two answers -- they give a clear and objective answer which of these two is simpler.

Comment: Not to mention that one of these solutions (the believed "simplest") produces wrong results, and that both of these are slower than the one I came up with. In particular your "simplest" solution. :)

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, In relation to 'wrong results', I re-tested both solutions, and I can't see any error. The output appears to be identical to the OP's provided expected output. As for simpicity, even after having a second and closer inspection, I am happy for my claims to rest. Perhaps it's a matter of perspective or personal style, but I am quiet satisfied with my solutions.

Comment: Sean, Just try with the XML document from my answer. As for your claims for having the "simplest" solution, I am glad that you are satisfied with your solutions. This, however has nothing to do with absolute statements that are contrary to the facts. With all due respect, if I am allowed to recommend something, it would be to test a solution thoroughly -- with different and really representative inputs, and to try to avoid absolute statements as much as possible. I believe, that you can do this. :)

Comment: Ok, I ran my first solution with your input document, and I see what you mean - our results are different. However, I don't think that my results are in error. By my interpretation of the OP's question, the extraneous category nodes are justified and explainable. However, in case I have got it wrong, I will post my results of your input data, and allow the OP to advise if I have misunderstood the rules of transformation.

Comment: Sean, The OP has explicitly asked in a comment made 17 hours ago, "to avoid duplicates and support n-level categories". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876695/transpose-character-separated-list-to-hierarchy-using-xsl/12877107#comment17433936_12877107

Comment: I think that was in reference to duplicate input nodes (like `<category>För honom > Badkläder</category>`) not resulting in duplicate output.

Comment: I still believe that my solution is correct. Until the OP comes out with a clarification, we are going to have to agree to disagree, and leave it at that.

Comment: Hi Sean, @DimitreNovatchev is right. This transformation is for extracting category tree from a product feed. So duplicates should be avoided. Both yours and Dimitres solutions are done with XSLT 2.0 which I don't think is supported by my VS2010 (it gives me compilation errors). Is there a way to do this with XSLT 1.0 using simple recursion? I came up with a solution for which I don't think is very elegant, but I'll adjust it and post here to hear your opinion.

Comment: @JovicaZaric, I think the same is possible with XSLT 1.0, but requires more complicated code. When I have time I'll post the respective XSLT 1.0 solution.

Comment: Just found out that my recursion is not filtering duplicates properly. Still looking for XSLT 1.0 solution...